# Adding a column in R ratio

Tags: r

I want to add a column in R. The value in this column should be column C <- column A divided by column B. so it would look like this

```
name
A 10, 20, 16, 12, 8
B 2, 5, 4, 3, 2
C 5, 4, 4, 4, 4
```

Im messing up the styling..

Comment: Just do  `transform(name, C = A/B)`

Answer (score 0):

Is your data frame called "name"? It doesn't matter what its called so long as you are referring to it.

I can do this in about 3 lines of code. First I made a dataframe with one column A in it, and then I added B, and then I finally added C with a formula with respect to A and B.

> name = data.frame(A = c(10, 20, 16, 12, 8))
>
> name$B = c(2, 5, 4, 3, 2)
>
> name$C = name$A / name$B
>
> View(name)

Maybe you wan to transpose it. Then it will look exactly like the one you gave me.

> t(name)